# rmdformats::material changing the color scheme of green and grey

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I would like to change the colors of the material theme in rmdformats. For example instead of green, perhaps use blue for the top portion. Here is a reprex (r notebook, run in Rtudio):

```
---
output: rmdformats::material
css: custom.css
---


# Introduction 

Some Intro

# Another Section

Section Info
```

My understanding is I can put "css: name_of_your_css.css" in the pre-amble, and play with the styling that way, however my css has zero affect on the knitted html, even if put !important after the properties I'm trying to change.

Comment: Hm. Worked fine on my machine. Changed the `background-color` of the `.header-panel` to red, adjusted the `font-family` in the `body` to times and changed the `color` of header 1 to red via selector ` .pages h1`.

Comment: can you post your css code @stefan? Maybe I'm doing something worng in the css.

Comment: Just posted it as answer.

Comment: Is your preamble the same as mine? @stefan

Comment: Yes. For sure. (; Pasted your code in an empty rmd. BTW: I just added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `custom.css` I treid:

```
body {
  font-family: times, serif;
  color: #000000;
}

.header-panel {
  background-color: #E40019;
}

.pages h1 {
  color: #E40019;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I modified my custom.css file to match yours, but doesn't affect my output at all...

Comment: I don't know, doesn't work on my end, I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: works! I was knitting expecting the css file to save... but after updating the css you have to manually save lol, thanks!

Comment: ((: Yes. Quite familiar with this kind of "stupid mistake" ... (;